# How to do incremenatal search in Vim like it is done in Emacs?

Tags: vim, incremental-search

When using incremental search in vim, the cursor immediately goes to the next occurrence of the search term as far as you have typed it. Emacs has a similar incremental search function. However, there is a feature of emacs isearch that I have found very useful that I really would like in vim. In emacs, if you type:

`<ctrl-s>word`

it immediately goes to "word", just like vim incremental search. In emacs, you can now type additional `<ctrl-s>` to move to the next result occurrence of "word" and in emacs *this does not end your incremental search session*. To do the same in vim, you must hit `<cr>`, to end the search term, then hit `n` to go to the next search result. Because emacs does not end the search session, you can do things like:

`<ctrl-s>word<ctrl-s><ctrl-s>more`

This lets you "home in" on your search once you get closer to where you want to go and turns out to be incredibly useful!

Is there a way to get vim to do the same?

Comment: How about this sequence: 1) `/word`, 2) `<CR>`, 3) `n`, ..., `n`, 4) `/`, 5, `<UP>`? You'll return to your search command, i.e. `/word`. Then you can continue entering `more`.

Comment: Yes, that works (and is roughly what I do now), it's just that its less convenient than the emacs version. Vim should be _more_ convenient than emacs at all times! ;-)

Comment: Of course the hardest part is hitting `<UP>`, you could instead use `<C-r>/` to insert search register that is contains your previous searched item.

Comment: '/' - to initiate a search

'Ctrl-l' - to expand search pattern using characters after the cursor (similar to 'Ctrl-w' in emacs).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Recent versions of Vim provide builtin mappings of command-line mode to do exactly what you want.

You can find this in [help](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-G):

> <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd>
>
> When `'incsearch'` is set, entering a search pattern for `"/"` or
>                   `"?"` and the current match is displayed then <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd> will move to the next match (does not take search-offset into account).  Use <kbd>CTRL-T</kbd> to move to the previous match.  Hint: on a regular keyboard <kbd>T</kbd> is above <kbd>G</kbd>.

Patch numbers for reference as not all installations have the mappings:

- Patch 7.4.2259 made <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> act like <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> in Emacs.
- Patch 7.4.2268 changed the mappings to <kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl-T</kbd> (the ones used initially have different purpose).

Comment: I upgraded vim, and this works! However, the keymappings by yolenoyer and Ruslan are actually better: They let me continue on an old search! Ctrl-T/Ctrl-G does not let me append on the previous search, which is at the core of what I want.

Comment: @00prometheus What do you mean by saying that you can't append to previous search? Pattern remains in place for me and I can continue editing it.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out now! Simply do a search, hit `<ctrl-g>/<ctrl-t>` and type some more to home in without leaving search at all. Perfect!

Answer (score 6):

The two mappings below let me hit `<Tab>` or `<S-Tab>` to jump to the next or previous match without leaving incremental search:

```
" needed for mapping <Tab> in command-line mode
set wildcharm=<C-z>

cnoremap <expr> <Tab>   getcmdtype() == "/" \|\| getcmdtype() == "?" ? "<CR>/<C-r>/" : "<C-z>"
cnoremap <expr> <S-Tab> getcmdtype() == "/" \|\| getcmdtype() == "?" ? "<CR>?<C-r>/" : "<S-Tab>"
```

Comment: What is the advantage of the getcmdtype conditional compared to just plain keymapping? This is deeper into vim than I am accustomed to go :-)

Comment: Right now, I have `nnoremap <C-s> /<UP>`
`cnoremap <C-s> <CR>/<UP>`
`cnoremap <C-z> <CR>?<UP>`, in my .vimrc. It allows me to use ctrl-s to go forwards and ctrl-z to go back.

Comment: @00prometheus: This is a nice emulation of xaizek's answer for older Vim versions.

Comment: If you add `zv` after the first `<CR>`, it will also open folds if needed. E.g. `cnoremap <expr> <Tab> getcmdtype() == "/" \|\| getcmdtype() == "?" ? "<CR>zv/<C-r>/" : "<C-z>"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a key mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-s> /<Up>
```

*(for normal mode)*

If you want to stay the the previous match (not to move to the next match), you may just return to the previous match after `/<Up>`:

```
nnoremap <C-s> N/<Up>
```

Usage:

1. `/word<CR>` - start searching for `word`
2. `n`, ..., `n` - move to the next matches
3. `<C-s>`, i.e. `Control + s` - call the previous search (1)
4. Type `more` - start searching for `/wordmore`

Comment: This is getting us there! I also tried adding `:cnoremap <C-s> <CR>n/<Up>` as well, so I can hit `ctrl-s` to go to the next match without leaving the search at all, but that jumps two results at a time. Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: @00prometheus, how about `nnoremap <C-s> N/<Up>`?

Comment: @yolenoyer figured it out; see his answer!

Comment: @00prometheus, his solution doesn't work for me. But my mapping works just as it is described in the question.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. I am using `nnoremap <C-s> /<Up>` and `cnoremap <c-s> <cr>/<up>`in my .vimrc now, and it works great! Now I just need to find a free key for reverse-isearch as well! :-)

Comment: If you also add `cnoremap <C-z> <CR>?<Up>` you can use ctrl-z to go back as well as ctrl-s to go forwards (ctrl-z isn't used in command mode otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

With the same idea:

```
:cnoremap <c-s> <cr>/<up>
```

With this mapping, he use of <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> during search is even more useful.

Comment: I tried this as well, but when I do it, the search jumps two results at a time. Are you getting different results?

Comment: If you change @Ruslans's mapping to be `nnoremap <C-s> /<Up>` as well, then it seems to work!